# Xcode-like Navigator control

Tags: xcode, menu, navigation, nssegmentedcontrol

What type of control is this? Some sort of Segment control but without borders? It works like a menu in that you can mouse down and drag... it will highlight as you drag and pick the one you release on.

[image: Xcode Navigator]

How can I do something similar?

The big difference I need is to allow multiple selection which will show different sets of details in the area below it. I can do this with a series of NSButtons, but don't get the drag-over "menu" effect.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have come across two example of implementation of Xcode-like inspector views:

https://github.com/malcommac/DMTabBar

https://github.com/smic/InspectorTabBar

Some time has passed, so they seem to me more the style of Xcode 4, but they should be ready to adapt to the new appearance.